# Filling up the bytes in an int variable

Tags: c, int, byte, bit

There are two variables,

```
uint8_t x (8 bit type)
uint16_t y (16 bit type)
```

, that together hold information about the value of an int *num*. Say *num* consists of four bytes **abcd** (where a is most significant). Then x needs to be copied to b, and y needs to be compied to cd. What is the best way/code to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
   uint8_t x = 0xF2;
   uint16_t y = 0x1234;
   int a = 0x87654321;

   // The core operations that put x and y in a.
   a = (a & 0xFF000000) | (x<<16);
   a = (a & 0xFFFF0000) | y;

   printf("x: %X\n", x);
   printf("y: %X\n", y);
   printf("a: %X\n", a);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
x: F2
y: 1234
a: 87F21234
```

Comment: I would recommend using `uint32_t` instead of `int` for the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Bytemasks will do. something like below

```
int8 x = a & 0xff;
int16 y = a & 0xff00;
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? Where are x and y?

Comment: I think the OP wants the reverse operation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a union (although be careful with padding/alignment)

```
typedef union 
{
  uint32_t abcd;
  struct 
  {
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    uint16_t cd;
  } parts;
} myvaluetype;

myvaluetype myvalue = {0};
uint8_t x = 42;
uint16_t y = 2311;

myvalue.parts.b = x;
myvalue.parts.cd = y;

printf( "%u\n", myvalue.abcd );
```